# Opposite of "Shopping Cart," for sellers?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

What's an appropriate term for a "shopping cart" when you're adding things to the cart and then selling them as opposed to buying?

This is for a web app but to help explain what I mean, the context in a real world example would be a seller that has a warehouse full of inventory. They get an order and say they grab a box and put the things they're about to sell in that box. Then they ship the box.

Is there a more appropriate term for the items the seller is gathering; the subset of their inventory that is just about to be sold?

Comment: Please look at what you're asking. What relationship between buyer and seller might there be but a "shopping cart?"

Comment: maybe "showcase"?

Comment: "order crate" or something.  or just 'pending-order' or "working-order" if it is a list of things, not a physical collection of things being readied. ( generally I guess an 'order' is completed purchase ? but not always  )

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin that's exactly my problem. I'm looking for a different term to use for buy side and sell side. I'll clarify a bit since I'm not being clear enough.

Comment: @Tom22 thanks, "pending-order" and "work-order" probably are closest concepts to what I'm looking for, and neither are things I'd thought of. Appreciate it.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, if you don't have an answer, you don't need to participate; more accurately, you shouldn't.

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer. I'd note that I have a bit of an issue with **work order** that you mentioned as I think that is different from a **working-order** as I explain in my answer.

Comment: This is called a *pick bin*. *Picking* is what you do when filling an order. See any glossary of warehouse and material management terms.

Comment: I always think of **pallets** as the place where wholesale merchandise is loaded prior to shipping to retailers. Would that work?

Comment: @PhilSweet thanks, I think *pick bin* is closest to what I'm after.

Comment: 'Offered goods' expresses what is for sale in any context, be it shop, stall, online website, catalogue or just printed list.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin given the many helpful and thoughtful responses, clearly you're in the wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a sellers perspective the items in a buyers shopping cart are seen as progress toward an order.  Often when someone looks into a shopping cart a sample 'order' is prepared for the customer, encouraging them to look at that prepared-order and complete the purchase.

Of course, usually an 'order', without qualification, is known to be a completed order.

.. the yet to be completed, potential order made of of the items in the card might be called -- (using my wording, not claiming these are industry jargon):

- a '**pending-order**' 
  or
- "**working-order**" or
- **potential order**  (although, this is often even more vague and even a look at an item or a marketing of an item before it makes it to a cart might be called a potential order internally - I would not recommend this as much)

In the comments to a comment I made before turning this into an answer he read **work order** however I am not sure that is right, because in many industries I have heard **work order** to mean a *completed service based order* (more like at a mechanic shop or repair visit, or an internal custom fabrication that needs to be performed as it has been confirmed and paid for)

**After purchase** but in the process of fulfilling the order for a customer:

If this were an order confirmed by customer but in the process of being filled other terms like '**order-crate**' (like a basket in a warehouse being filled but not yet packed ?) or maybe a "***order-in-progress***" might work.

@Phil_Sweet , in a comment, mentions an industry term '**pick bin**' which sounds like it might be the industry term for items being aggregated in a warehouse off the list of items on a completed order, prior to packing and delivery.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating and especially about *working-order* vs *work-order*.

Answer (score 0):

I believe "inventory" would do it quite nicely.

Comment: Thanks, thought about that but inventory is everything that is available to sell, not what is up for the current sale.

Comment: @SamuelNeff - Things that are part of the current sale are *currently on sale* or *on special*. "They get an order" - that's *an order*; it should contain what's listed on the *invoice*.

Answer (score 0):

Catalog or showcase, maybe. I'm not sure I understood exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I added more text to the question to help explain what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

The term for the [list of] items is an *invoice*.

> in·voice /ˈinˌvois/ noun
>     1.    a list of goods sent or services provided, with a statement of the sum due for these; a bill.
>
> – [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=invoice%20definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b)

---

> An [**invoice**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invoice), bill or tab is a commercial document issued by a seller to a buyer, relating to a sale transaction and **indicating the products, quantities, and agreed prices for products or services** the seller had provided the buyer.
>
> Payment terms are usually stated on the invoice. These may specify that the buyer has a maximum number of days in which to pay and is sometimes offered a discount if paid before the due date. **The buyer could have already paid for the products or services** listed on the invoice.
>
> – Wiki

---

*'When you're adding things to the cart to sell them'* - that's *consignment*.

> con·sign·ment /kənˈsīnmənt/ noun
>     a batch of goods destined for or delivered to someone.
>
> – [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=consignment%20definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b)

Answer (score 0):

If the goods are, in fact, being shipped,
then ***shipment*** seems to be appropriate. 
If you’re just putting together the purchases
of a customer who is on the premises,
then some of the other answers (notably “order”) may be better.